# How to subscribe only to a specific category of videos in a YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube

I find most of the [Tobuscus](http://www.youtube.com/user/Tobuscus) YouTube videos boring. But I like the "Cute Win Fail" ones. Can I be notified only when he uploads such videos, instead of subscribing to them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible anymore. It used to be, but they removed this functionality when they updated to the new playlist format/layout.